# LaTeX nodes with text do not align vertically

Tags: latex

I would like to align the text in two nodes vertically. My current implementation is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,0) {depot};
        \node[anchor=west] at (2,0) {satellite};        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

This returns the following figure

[image]

As you can see, the words are not well aligned in the vertical direction. This is caused by the "p" in depot. What argument should I add to \node to have them vertically aligned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `\strut` you can "fake" a letter of maximal height and depth:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,0) {depot\strut};
        \node[anchor=west] at (2,0) {satellite\strut};        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

or if you don't need your `west` anchor, you can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=base] at (0,0) {depot};
        \node[anchor=base] at (2,0) {satellite};        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```